# Laravel 5.2 Sessions Not Working Properly

Tags: laravel, session, null

I am working on laravel 5.2 project and have a problem with sessions. When I create a session, I can only access it from the blade template. If I want to access it from any of other classes, it is not possible. I'am using Laravel 5.2 and all of my routes are inside of the 'web' middleware. I searched the entire web but none of them has provided a solution to my problem.

Session creation code:

```
<?php namespace App\Lib\Services;

$this->request->session()->put('errors', $this->errors);`   
redirect()->back()->send();
```

When I test the session in the view like below, it works (gives the intended data):

```
@extends('themes.backend.metronic.main')

@section('pageContent')
{{ dd(session ('errors')) }}
@endsection
```

However, If I want to use it another class like below, it returns null:

```
namespace App\Lib\Themes\Errors;

function __construct($specs)
    {
        parent::__construct($specs);
        $this->setData();
        dd(session('errors')); // this returns null value
        $this->setErrorMsg();
    }
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: when your class is constructed the session data is empty so that's why you get null. Have you tried to access it from any other function?

Comment: Create your session like session('key', 'value'); and use it like session('key');

Comment: either session('key', 'value') method not working. I can not use sessions anywhere except views.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing your session variable within a constructor of the class, it could be that your class is being created before you can set your session variables. Try setting your session variables first, and then create a new object of that class.